# java doctor appointment reservation database (mysql) program..having trouble designing the appointments schema

Tags: java, mysql

I need to build a program in Java that uses MySQL to store the doctors' appointments. I have a rough idea that I need a table to keep track of the Doctor's id, Patient's id, and the appointment date and time in the same table. Am I missing any other attributes? I assume I would need a compareTo method in my Java implementation to check for the available times. I hope I have made it clear to what I want to accomplish.
Currently, I have a Doctor table and a Patient table, both having their own id as their primary key. I am using Hibernate to map the object oriented design with my relations in MySQL if that matters.

Comment: The only question I see here "Am I missing any other attributes?" and it seems you've answered it yourself.  If not, it depends on too many factors of your app that this community could not possibly know about.

Comment: Sorry. My question here is how to go about designing a database table that will keep track of all my appointments for my program. I think if I can get some ideas, I will be able to figure this out on my own.

Answer (score 4):

## Date-Time Is One Value

Date-time values are almost always tracked in software as single values. Technically they are represented internally as a count of seconds/milliseconds/microseconds/nanoseconds since an [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29).

You may want to present a date and a time separately in the user interface, but not internally.

Also, you almost certainly should be thinking about time zones. Naïve programmers often think they can ignore time zones, but that is almost certain to cause anguish later.

## Understand Your Database’s Handling of Date-Time

Different databases handle date-time differently. Absolutely crucial that you read the docs, play around, experiment, and learn exactly how your database works.

[Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/) has excellent and sensible handling of date-time. Even if you use another database, consult the excellent Postgres documentation on [date-time data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) and [date-time functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) (commands) to learn about the various issues and about what is defined by the SQL standard versus peculiar to your database.

## Store Globally, Present Locally

Date-Time is a surprisingly slippery and complicated problem. One key to keeping a hold on the problem is working in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Store your date-time values in the database (or in serialized files, or XML/JSON communications) in UTC. Write most of your business logic in UTC, except where local time zone matters such as defining "the beginning of a new day".

When you present to the user, either use ISO 8601 format or localize to their own time zone (or the time zone they expect). This follows the basic idea of internationalization/localization. For text values, you use certain key strings in your code. Upon presentation in the user interface, you map those internal strings to localized (translated) text values for user interface. Some with date-time: UTC internally, local time zone in user interface.

One caveat: You might want to *also* store a local date-time for the sake of history. Time zone rules change frequently and capriciously because of politicians and bureaucrats. Your software's time zone database may be out of date. So you may want to store what you or the user believed to be a certain date-time *then*. But don't rely on it; determine and store the UTC value.

Tip: Learn to think and read in 24-hour time. Your life as a programmer/debugger/sysadmin will become some much easier and less error-prone.

## Joda-Time or java.time

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

Instead use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310).

Both libraries use ISO 8601 formats as their defaults, for both parsing and generating strings.

## ISO 8601

[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is a sensible standard defining how to present date-time values, time zones and offsets, durations, and periods in specific and non-ambiguous textual formats. Study that well-written Wikipedia page.

Note in particular what the standard calls [Durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). A span of time is defined in this format: `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` means "Period", the `T` separates the date portion from the time portion, and the other optional parts are digits + letter. A half-hour appointment would be `PT30M`. This may be handy for you, such as for the "period_" field seen in my [ERD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) below. In Joda-Time, the Period class represents a span of time by tracking its months, days, hours, etc., and knows how to both parse and generate strings in this format.

## Half-Open

You can choose to store appointments in either of two ways. One way is a start date-time & a duration (90 minutes, 20 minutes, etc.). Another way is to record both a start and stop date-time. In this case, the usual and generally best approach is called "Half-Open". This means the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

For example, a one-hour appointment on the hour would run from 11:00 to 12:00, meaning "starting at 11 AM and running up to, but not including, the first moment of the next hour (noon)". The next appointment will run from 12:00 to 13:00.

Search StackOverflow for "Half-open" to find more discussion and examples and diagrams.

## Many-To-Many

The relationship between *Patient* and *Doctor* is what we call [Many-To-Many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29). A doctor sees many patients, and a patient may see more than one of the doctors. Be sure you know about Many-To-Many tables in relational database design. The solution is always to add a third table, sometimes called a "bridge" table that serves as a child table to both of the other parent tables. In your case, the *Appointment* table is the bridge table.

You will need to know how to perform joins across a many-to-many relationship.

## Direct SQL

If you are new to programming or new to relational database, I suggest avoiding Hibernate. You really should get a grasp of what is going on. Hibernate has some appropriate uses. But if you think Hibernate is going to magically make database issues disappear, you’ll be disappointed.

## Attributes

Attributes are up to you. They depend on the business (or homework?) problem you are trying to solve. You have the basics right.

Appointment-scheduling is a very difficult business problem for which to write software. For example, are you simply recording appointments being made? Or are you tracking the availability of the doctors, by creating predefined time slots, and if so how do you handle exceptions and changes to each doctor’s calendar? You need to write very specific requirements and use-cases. Very easy for users’ expectations to exceed your supposed requirements.

Here's a simplistic view.

[image]